# Is there python asyncio equivalent of the threading world yield() or sleep(0) functions?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm writing some unittests (using asynctest). Imagine a minimal function:

```
async def foo(self):
     await self._bar_()
```

... with the associated unittest:

```
import asynctest as unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock

async def test_func(self):
    obj._bar_ = Mock()
    await obj.foo()
    obj._bar_.assert_awaited() # incorrectly asserts that bar hasn't been awaited
```

---

To address a point made by a comment: [asynctest](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynctest.mock.html) is the library I used for unittest asyncio code and it supports drop-in replacements for all unittest features mentioned in this code. Specifically as pointed out in the documentation:

> Enhance unittest.mock.Mock so it returns a CoroutineMock object instead of a Mock object where a method on a spec or spec_set object is a coroutine.

---

This doesn't work at face value because the event loop fires up the awaited `_bar_()` method only after the current `test_func()` task yields.

Asynctest provides a mechanism to synchronize by using `Mock().awaited.wait()`.

```
async def test_func(self):
    obj._bar_ = Mock()
    await obj.foo()

    await obj._bar_.awaited.wait()

    obj._bar_.assert_awaited() # correctly passes assertion test
```

The above works, however this doesn't work if we want to test instead with `assert_not_awaited`. Let's say I have another function:

```
async def baz(self):
    # do some stuff but never await on _bar_
```

...

```
async def test_func(self):
    obj._bar_ = Mock()
    await obj.baz()

    await obj._bar_.awaited.wait() # hangs forever
    obj._baz_.assert_not_awaited()
```

The only way I've found to reliably measure this test is to do as follows:

```
async def test_func(self):
    obj._bar_ = Mock()
    await obj.baz()

    with contextlib.suppress(asyncio.TimeoutError):
        await asyncio.wait_for(obj._bar_.awaited.wait(), timeout=0.01) # see note below on timeout

    obj._bar_.assert_not_awaited() # correctly asserts that `_bar_` was awaited
```

**Important:** this in fact means that I *always* have to use this method otherwise I can fool myself into thinking my assertions hold.

Note: I've tried this with a timeout of 0 and the behaviour reverts to the first case (i.e. wait_for simply immediately returns without any reording of task scheduling).

My understanding of what is happening here is that the `wait_for` with a timeout is essentially acting like a `yield()` or `sleep(0)` method from the threading world: i.e. it is putting the current task at the end of the event loop queue and allowing every other currently pending task to be flushed.

So my question is whether there is an `asyncio` native way of achieving this goal of yielding the current task to allow ventilating all other currently pending tasks?

Comment: "This doesn't work at face value because the event loop fires up the awaited `_bar_()` method only after the current `test_func()` task yields." - that's not how it works. It sounds like you may be mis-diagnosing a bug. Perhaps you meant `obj._bar_().assert_awaited()` - note the extra parentheses.

Comment: You are incorrect. `_bar_` is a `CoroutineMock` object. Notice how it is awaited correctly in the `foo` implementation. 

See the documentation in the link [here](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynctest.mock.html#asynctest.CoroutineMock). Coroutine (and normal) mocks can be called like a regular method, but also exposes `assert_*` functions.

Comment: `asyncio.sleep(0)`: "Skip one event loop run cycle." https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1cba1c9abadf76f458ecf883a48515aa3b534dbd/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L640

Comment: @Aaron that's fascinating. I totally got fooled by the difference in semantics of the `wait_for` primitive. Post this as a response and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @MB. Good to see your issue solved. `asyncio.wait_for` would cancel the future/task. If you want a pause, try `asyncio.wait`, `asyncio.sleep`, or `asyncio.as_completed`.

Comment: @Aaron: yes, I used `wait_for` specifically to issue a timeout on the `asynctest` library call to `awaitable.await`.

Comment: @MB.: "`_bar_` is a `CoroutineMock` object" - that's not what you posted. The code you posted just uses a regular `Mock`.

Comment: I appreciate the specification. I stated at the top that I'm using "asynctest". I'll make it clearer that asynctest is a drop-in replacement for unittest as specified in their documentation [here](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> A test author can import asynctest in place of unittest safely.

Comment: `from unittest.mock import Mock` is still importing from the regular `unittest`, not `asynctest`. The fact that you put `import asynctest as unittest` on the line above makes no difference.

Comment: Also, `asynctest.mock.Mock` wouldn't be a `CoroutineMock` either. You would need `asynctest.CoroutineMock` for that. `asynctest.mock.Mock` produces `CoroutineMock`s as *attributes* when a `spec` or `spec_set` indicates that that attribute should be a coroutine.

Comment: @user2357112: your initial suspicion that I had forgotten to call an awaitable was due to the way Mock objects work as functors: you were partially correct in having sniffed that out because, yes Mock objects do *not* fulfill the principle of least astonishment.

However, at this point, you are looking for something to call wrong. The *test* code above was correct and remains correct. What is incorrect is the imports I have declared while making my "minimal working example". More importantly, the principal question has been answered and it is unrelated to the mock object. Let's move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1cba1c9abadf76f458ecf883a48515aa3b534dbd/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L640):

> Skip one event loop run cycle.
>
> This is a private helper for 'asyncio.sleep()', used
>      when the 'delay' is set to 0.  It uses a bare 'yield'
>      expression (which Task.__step knows how to handle)
>      instead of creating a Future object.

Comment: This fulfills the question I had asked which was to find an equivalent of `Thread.sleep(0)`. Interestingly, even though there are no delays in the code I'm testing, it appears it is not sufficient to simply sleep(0) for the asynctest to execute the pending tasks.

It's such an edge case that I'm not exactly sure it's a bug. In any case, I will close the question as-is because [__sleep0()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1cba1c9abadf76f458ecf883a48515aa3b534dbd/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L640) was exactly what I was looking for.